# Javascript find occurrence of given div with its content in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, search

I'd need to search the DOM, possibly inside a div with `id="#box"`, to avoid searching the whole document, for the recurrence of given `"<div><br></div>"`
and delete all of em if any.

**I'm trying with:**

```
$('#box').html($('#box').html().replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g,''));
```

...but I have the impression it's deleting all divs whatsoever.
I also don't like the idea of using a regex for this.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, will [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) work for you?

Comment: @rmn I need to get/delete it only if it's exactly <div><br></div> , i wonder if :contains returns me all divs which contain a <br>?

Comment: `:contains` is for text only

Comment: @charlietfl True, makes sense. Looks like i misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `remove()` instead along with a filter that checks for only a single child `<br>`

Something like

```
$('#box div').has('br').filter(function(){
  return $(this).children().length === 1;   
}).remove()
```